# Remove useless zero digits from decimals

Tags: php

I need to delete useless zero but i have problem with `(float)` and `number_format()`

I have number like `0.00000010` and i need `0.0000001` but i have `0.0000` without `number_format` its good

My code

```
$number = (float)$number;
$number_array = explode('.', $number);
$left = $number_array[0];
$right = $number_array[1];
$number = number_format($number, strlen($right));
```

http://codepad.org/ondL9bg1

Comment: Zeros are never useless.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$number = rtrim($number, '0');
```

[rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) takes the character(s) to trim as a second (optional) argument.

If you want it to work also for integers (eg. `1000`), try this:

```
if (false !== strpos($number, '.'))
    $number = rtrim($number, '0');
```

Even better, to remove trailing dot in numbers like `0.00000`:

```
if (false !== strpos($number, '.'))
    $number = rtrim(rtrim($number, '0'), '.');
```

Comment: Thanks its work but i have problem for number over 0 ex 10 give 10. [link](http://codepad.org/IZpNl2zw)

Comment: @p4c Does that do the trick for you: `$number = 10.0000; echo (float)$number;` ?